# MultiSelect Dropdown with checkbox AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Is there any tag to create a multi select dropdown with checkboxes without writing the directive in AngularJS ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/docs/#/main)

```
// HTML
    <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example8data" selected-
      model="example8model" extra-settings="example8settings">
    </div>

// JavaScript

 $scope.example8model = [];
 $scope.example8data = [ 
                {id: 1, label: "David"},
                {id: 2, label: "Jhon"},
                {id: 3, label: "Danny"}
                ];
               $scope.example8settings = { checkBoxes: true, };
```

Answer (score 1):

**Not as a standard no.** 
You could create you're own directive or use an excisting one if you don't want to write your own like you stated.

Have a look at [AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect](http://%60http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/%60), and use the option `checkboxes`.

Comment: Adding `input` inside the `select` element wont' be enough? `<option *ngFor="let cust_list of customer_list" [value]="cust_list.id">
                        <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="cust_list.isSelected"> {{ cust_list.account_name }} [{{ cust_list.id }}]
                    </option>`

Answer (score 0):

You can also manage something like implemented in demo below.

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('multiSelectDemo', [ 'shalotelli-angular-multiselect' ])
.controller('MainCtrl', [ '$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.multiSelectData = [
    { id: 1, label: 'Option 1' },
    { id: 2, label: 'Option 2'},
    { id: 3, label: 'Option 3' },
    { id: 999, label: 'Other', isOther: true}
  ];
  
  $scope.selectedItems = [
      { id: 1, label: 'Option 1' }
  ]

  $scope.multiSelectOutput = [];
}]).config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
   $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
     'self',
     'http://*./**',
     'https://rawgit.com/**',
     'http://rawgit.com/**'
   ]);
  
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.2.0" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.1" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0-beta.5" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//rawgit.com/ncapito/angular-multiselect/master/multiselect.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//rawgit.com/ncapito/angular-multiselect/master/styles/multi-select.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="multiSelectDemo">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Shalotelli Angular Multiselect</h1>
      <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <multi-select 
        values="multiSelectData" 
        model="selectedItems" 
        show-filters="true" 
        show-other="true" 
        other-ng-model="other"
        other-field="isOther"
        other-event="keyup" 
        value-field="id" 
        label-field="label" 
        
        template-path="http://rawgit.com/ncapito/angular-multiselect/master/views/directives/multi-select.html"></multi-select>
        <hr />
        <p>Multi Select Data: </p>
        <pre>{{multiSelectData}}</pre>
        <p></p>
        <hr />
        <p>Multi Select Output: </p>
        <pre>{{selectedItems}}</pre>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Regards.

Comment: The question was with 'checkboxes'.

Comment: Yes i know, As answer says __You can also manage something like ...__

Comment: @HardikVaghani im getting an exception if i inject [ 'shalotelli-angular-multiselect' ]     Exception is "This error occurs when a module fails to load due to some exception. The error message above should provide additional context.

A common reason why the module fails to load is that you've forgotten to include the file with the defined module or that the file couldn't be loaded."

Comment: @HardikVaghani I guess no .Im getting error in Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at multiselect.js:327

Comment: i think its not getting reference of angular js. Try to put angular at top and then other reference libs.

Comment: @HardikVaghani  I am getting an error if i inject in angular.module itself saying "HeaderController is not a function,got undefined"

Comment: @HardikVaghani Adding `input` inside the `select` element wont' be enough? `<option *ngFor="let cust_list of customer_list" [value]="cust_list.id">
                        <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="cust_list.isSelected"> {{ cust_list.account_name }} [{{ cust_list.id }}]
                    </option>`